# Can't install a package with an error: "Currently it is not possible to install binary packages from a remote repository as root"

Tags: r, package

I was unable to install a R package through GUI `R.app` on macOS, using a package installer GUI. In the past, I was able to install it without any problems.

The problem is when I tried to install a package, an error `Currently it is not possible to install binary packages from a remote repository as root.` occurred. I might not be good at the system-level knowledge, so want to use GUI as I have used it. But what is preventing the GUI from working any longer? Maybe from Yosemite it is no longer working?

[image]

And finally, is it still possible to use GUI package installer in this situation?

---

#### UPDATE

Hmmm... It seems that after updating to 3.3.1 (I used 3.3), the problem has gone away. I can install packages both at User Level and System Level without any problems. I don't know why, but someone can clarify it in case I would face the same problem in the future?

Comment: Why don't you just run it as a regular user instead of admin?

Comment: @Hack-R I'm not sure if I get your question, but by selecting "At User Level", I tried to install it as a regular user, right?